# OSX El Capitan and http_proxy with specific path to proxypac

Tags: macos, http-proxy

Standard corporate environment, forcing clients to got through a proxy server via a proxypac. In the OSX configuration is in the following format:

```
http://www.proxy.server.name:8080/proxy_pac_path_to_package.pac
```

Trying to connect via CLI, for a homebrew install, and used (so far) the following options:

```
export http_proxy=http://www.proxy.server.name:8080/proxy_pac_path_to_package.pac

export http_proxy=http://www.proxy.server.name:8080

export http_proxy=http://myusername:mypasswd@www.proxy.server.name:8080/proxy_pac_path_to_package.pac

export http_proxy=http://myusername:mypasswd@www.proxy.server.name:8080
```

with mypasswd special characters being mapped into their hex code, and with username using either the "simple" form, or the entire AD path, or the email, etc.

None of the above worked. Any idea about what I may be missing, from one's own experience through non-obvious things?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it can no longer be reproduced.

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't have access to your particular corporate environment, I can't make a definitive diagnosis, but the first thing I'd try is exporting `https_proxy` and `all_proxy` with the same value (note that the `https_proxy` may not have an `https:` URL; it has whatever the `http_proxy` is). Your various selections of values were the correct ones to try (though I've seen very odd encodings of username/password, so I wouldn't write that off). I would make sure that Safari works through the proxy, and if you need to login to the proxy via Safari, you do so. If Safari isn't working through the proxy, there's basically zero chance that Homebrew will.

As a second thing to try (though this is voodoo and may just be cargo culting), you could try setting it, instead of to the `http:` schema, to the `socks5:` schema, otherwise leaving the rest of the URL the same. I've seen this work because certain proxies are more geared towards Windows clients and still have old code, and because of the poor record of interoperability between Windows versions' TCP stacks, SOCKS was more reliable.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. Here is what "throws me off: - all examples I have seen, so far, end at the FQDN:PORT config. For some reasons my proxy config, pushed from the enterprise, has the pac AFTER the port... and yes - Safari and Chrome work fine. I will try your other suggestions - https makes the most sense, next

Comment: Pardon if I'm misunderstanding, but the path to the PAC _has_ to go after the FQDN:PORT, because the format of a URL must be `schema://username@host:port/path/name` (with some of those items being optional). If the PAC came before the port, it wouldn't be a port anymore, but an addition to the path name.

Answer (score 0):

Unbelievable!!! A huge DUH on my part: had two iTerm windows opened in the same time - I was doing the export http_proxy in one, from the CLI, and testing connectivity in the other (which was running another shell session, of course, with no awareness of the exported variables in the one I was making changes in)... can't believe how stupid this was. Sorry for all the noise... and thanks to @Trey to assuming I was not an idiot :-)